# Buying a used car in Ontario - safety certificate

Tags: used, buying

I am planning on buying a used vehicle privately.  But it needs a bit of work before it will pass a safety check.  Nothing major, but cash is tight and I may have to wait a few weeks before I can do the repairs.

In the mean time, I want to put my current car up for sale, and keep driving it until either someone buys it (in which case I can fix the newer one right away) or I have the new one ready to go.

But the whole process of transfering ownership, insurance, getting the safety test, and still driving my old car is confusing me.

If I transfer the ownership right away, the car becomes unfit.  Then I have to have it towed to the mechanic to do the safety test?

What is the proper order of fixing the car, transfering ownership, transfering insurance from my old car to newer one, etc?

Comment: You're probably better asking this locally in Ontario, as it's a very location-specific question. In the UK, we have a specific exception to allow cars to be driven to the annual safety check even if the previous one has expired, but we have a recent rule that says all cars must be insured at all times, unless officially declared as "off the road" (previously you could simply keep a car off the road for a short time without declaring it as such, and not insure it). I suspect you have similar peculiarities!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this a localized regulatory issue